# 2 Action Connections in IB to one Button

Tags: xcode, button, interface-builder, connection, action

I have an xcode app that I am building using IB for mac.  THe app launches with windowA already opened.  There is a button on WindowA that when pressed I would like to open WindowB and Consequently close WindowA.

I have found in the tutorials that there can only be 1 sent action connection per object, so all I can do at this point is have windowA close, or call WindowB to open on top.

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish both using the same button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, you can call a single method. But within this method, you may accomplish several things. For example close a window and open another.

It's not necessary to create a complete class - which would correspond to a .m file. You just add another method

```
- (IBAction) doIt:(id) sender
```

to an existing class file. Connect this to your button in IB. Therefore, you set "File's Owner" to the class where your IBAction is (or, better, put the IBAction method in "File's Owner" class file). 
In interface builder, select menu item File>Reload all class files
Now, right click "File's Owner" in interface builder. You should see your action there. Drag the round circle on the right of the popup to your button. Now, each time your button is clicked, the method should be called.

Comment: sorry to sound like a Newbie here, but I learned C++ in College 10 years ago, and this is my first cocoa project.  A method would be a .m file, like my main.m correct?  So I would simply make a new file calling cocoa and nswindow headers and code the actions, then make a connection in IB for that button to the .m file I created correct?

Comment: ... I tried to explain in more detail. The simplest way would be a screencast :)

Comment: Thanks... this makes more sense...  I have been attempting in IB, and there is simply no way to do it.  Screencast would be fantastic.

Comment: Yeah - took me a while as well. Still, as I don't use it daily, I have to check how I already solved problems to copy that to new problems...